# What's the word for an initial outpouring of creativity?

Tags: single-word-requests

If someone picks up an instrument, paintbrush, starts writing, or other creative activity for the first time and they experience a 'gush' of initial production or output. There's a word for it, but totally forgot it?

Comment: Are you looking for a noun, a verb? Please check out the [single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info) tag as there are specific criteria. Hopefully something inspirational will manifest. –

Comment: Are you thinking of something like “beginners luck” or “natural talent/ a natural” or “a knack for something”

Comment: You have already discovered a very good one by yourself - namely "a gush of...".

Comment: [First flush](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/the-first-flush-of-something) is 2 words but describes this.

Answer (score 0):

That would be a *Burst* of creativity. What we always look forward to and always wish we could find again. However, the older we get the better we were. [Now I need a source]

Comment: Hrm.. nope, there's a specific word definition that encapsulates the meaning - of the 'first' rush of creativity... Not just a 'burst' 'gush' etc..